# Java runnable and interfaces

Tags: java, interface, runnable

I'm trying to implement a `UserInterface` interface, which always needs to run in a thread (so is `Runnable`). So I have code like this, where `SpecificInterface` implements `UserInterface`:

```
UserInterface myUI = new SpecificInterface(...);
Thread thread = new Thread(myUI);
thread.start();
```

But this obviously doesn't work, because I can't make `UserInterface` implement `Runnable` since interfaces can't implement other interfaces. And I can't just make `SpecificInterface` runnable since that defeats the point of using interfaces.

How am I supposed to make this work? Do I need to make `UserInterface` an abstract class, or create a `RunnableInterface` abstract class which implements `UserInterface` and `Runnable` and inherit my UI's from it, or..? I am rather confused as to why the "simple" solution can't work.

Googling was less than helpful, all I find is links telling me how to use the "Runnable interface" :|

Comment: Show the `UserInterface` and the `SpecficInterface` class?

Comment: @JoshM They are way too big to be shown here. But basically they all have a custom event dispatcher loop in the `run()` method (this is for an exercise).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interfaces can extend other interfaces.

```
interface UserInterface extends Runnable {
    void someOtherFunction();
    // void run() is inherited as part of the interface specification
}

public class SpecificInterface implements UserInterface {
    @Override
    public void someOtherFunction() {
        . . .
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        . . .
    }
}
```

Comment: `UserInterface` would have to `extends` `Runnable`. It appears that `SpecificInterface` is a sub-interface of `UserInterface` (judging from his declaration statement).

Comment: @JoshM - Sorry; I had names backwards.

Comment: That works great, thanks! Didn't know about `extend`ing interfaces!